# Need help formatting pandas data frame from json file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need help formatting a json file that I converted to a pandas dataframe.

Json looks like

```
{
  "test":
    { 
       "1":["test1_a", "test1_b", "test1_c"]
       "2":["test2_a", "test2_b", "test2_c"]
       "3":["test3_a", "test3_b", "test3_c"]
     }
}
```

And I need this json to be converted to a pandas dataframe and for it to be printed like this:

```
col1     col2     col3
test1_a  test1_b  test1_c
test2_a  test2_b  test2_c
test3_a  test3_b  test3_c
```

How would I do this? I need it to be a pandas dataframe and need to define the column rows.

So far I have tried:

```
json_file = open(json_file_path, 'r') 
data = json.load(json_file)
pandasDataframe = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(data)
print(pandasDataframe)
```

And it prints this, which I don't want :(

```
1 ["test1_a", "test1_b", "test1_c"]
2 ["test2_a", "test2_b", "test2_c"]
3 ["test3_a", "test3_b", "test3_c"]
```

updated: when I do

```
pd.DataFrame(data['test'])
```

It looks like [not quite what I want, but it's getting there]

```
     1        2        3
0 test1_a   test2_a  test3_a
1 test1_b   test2_b  test3_b
2 test1_c   test2_c  test3_c
```

Update #2: when I transpose it looks like this:

```
        0               2
1 test1_a test1_b test1_c
2 test2_a test2_b test2_c
3 test3_a test3_b test3_c
```

How would I get rid of the 0 and 2 at the top? And what does it mean?
Also how do I get rid of the 1,2,3 (aka the first column altogether)

desired output:
the col names (col1, col2, col3) need to be added, but don't know how)

```
col1     col2     col3
test1_a  test1_b  test1_c
test2_a  test2_b  test2_c
test3_a  test3_b  test3_c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

```
pd.DataFrame(data['test']).T.rename(columns={0:'col1',1:'col2',2:'col3'})
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2     col3
1  test1_a  test1_b  test1_c
2  test2_a  test2_b  test2_c
3  test3_a  test3_b  test3_c
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything at all

Comment: Could you add what outputs when you do `print(data)`? @SOScodehelp

Comment: Sorry tried it again and it basically prints what I wanted, but the rows are the columns and the columns are row if that makes sense, it's basically flipped!

Comment: Do you know how I could flip it around? @MrNobody33

Comment: You mean like [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the dataframe with `df.T`? @SOScodehelp

Comment: I posted the updated version when I do df.T and it does work, but I get a weird thing at the top! Also how would I add in the name of the columns?

Comment: And delete the first column as well?

Comment: Added the desired output!

Comment: How would I add the name of the columns? and delete the "0               2"

Comment: with rename you could do that? the 0,1,2 are the rows names, that when you transposed they get as the column names @SOScodehelp

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much It works!! Sorry one last thing, how can I get rid of the first column, the 1, 2, and 3 ?

Comment: That´s not the first column, that´s the index of the dataframe. So, I suggest you to see the documentation basics of pandas. But if you want to keep the first `"col1"` as the index, you could try with `df.set_index("col1")`. Also, if the answer works for you, [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it please!:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218656/discussion-between-soscodehelp-and-mrnobody33).

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you need [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html#pandas-dataframe-add-prefix)

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data['test']).add_prefix('col')
```

---

```
      col1     col2     col3
0  test1_a  test2_a  test3_a
1  test1_b  test2_b  test3_b
2  test1_c  test2_c  test3_c
```